# How do I concatenate variables with a string to create an Oracle table name in a FROM clause in a stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, syntax, oracle10g, dynamic-sql

e.g.

```
select * 
  from v_schema || '.tbl_a@' || abc.world
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic sql:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm .

To protect against sql injection you can use `dbms_assert`:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_assert_10gR2.php

Answer (score 0):

You're not really supposed to do this but [here](http://thinkoracle.blogspot.com/2005/09/column-name-as-variable.html) are several ways.

Answer (score 0):

-- Dynamic SQL

> execute immediate 'select * from ' ||
>   v_schema || '.tbl_a@abc.world';